# Login System let's anyone login (new to PHP)

Tags: php, authentication

So i'm new to and learning PHP, I have a login system that should check if the username and password match that in a database and if so it will log the user in however you can type anything into the form and it logs the user in I have a login form that takes you to this page.

```
<?php
include 'Connection.php';
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
//checking if the user is coming from the form
{
$Username=$_POST['Username'];
$Password=$_POST['Password'];
//$Admin = $_GET['UserType'];

$query="SELECT * FROM Users 
WHERE Username = '$Username' AND Password ='$Password' AND UserType ='admin' OR UserType =''";
//checking if theirs a match of username and password

$result=mysqli_query($Connection, $query);
//checking if their is a match

if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $_SESSION['Username'] = $Username.'  '.$row['UserType'].'';
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'success';



    include'Login.php';

    //if a match is found
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['error']='User not recognised';
    header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");

    //if a match isn't found
   }
   }
      else
     {
           header('location: Home.php');
     }

 if ($row['UserType'] == 'admin'){
      $_SESSION['admin'] = true;
  }


  ?>
```

Comment: This `if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){` could be an empty array

Comment: When using both AND and OR in your query, use parentheses to group the bits that need to be evaluated together. I'm guessing it should be `WHERE Username = '$Username' AND Password ='$Password' AND (UserType ='admin' OR UserType ='')`

Comment: SQLInjection `$_POST['username'] = "' OR 1 LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0--"` there now I can login as anyone I want to.

Comment: Besides the SQL Injection previously mentioned, you should not store passwords in plain text. Use password_hash/password_verify

Comment: Hi, I'm working on encryption and validation next i'm just learning php as part of a module for uni but wanted to get a working login system before i move to more advanced features but thank you @Don'tPanic

Comment: Thank you @aynber that fixed it for me, i think i broke it whilst adding the admin option but it works now, thank you

Comment: I'm almost certain aynber's right. Without the parentheses, it's probably interpreting that WHERE clause as (username+password+type=admin) OR (type='')